# STRIPE payment checkout Integration into DOTNET Core 5 with Razor

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I have integrated STRIPE Payment checkout into my C# DOT NET CORE 5 WEB with Razor. In my development and test environment i.e. my PC with http://localhost:4242 and IIS Express (VS 2019) the WEB App successfully executes the call to STRIPE's API and displays the payment page. However when I publish the app (VS 2019) to the server (it's hosted on my PC using IIS) the Payment page doesn't get activated.

I have ensured that the Domain in the server version has been changed to https://MyWebSite.com.

Has anyone experienced this before and know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "Payment page doesn't get activated"? Can you share some example code detailing how you integration works? Are you encountering any errors you can share? You need to provide more detail to allow us to help you.

Comment: There are two pages here : a) the html page that displays three product price breaks, and b) the controller page that gets the .env parameters and directs the request to the STRIPE payments API

Comment: Pricing.cshtml  <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">US$10.10 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        </ul>
                        <button id="pro-plan-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Academic</button>
                    </div>

Comment: .env     # Stripe keys
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

# Required to run webhook
# See README on how to use the Stripe CLI to setup
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=whsec_123...

# Stripe subscription data
# DOMAIN=http://localhost:4242
DOMAIN=https://www.MyWebsite.com
BASIC_PRICE_ID=price_1It55AGb0WWi7xoEcnF97NQb
PRO_PRICE_ID=price_1It6BtGb0WWi7xoEm96BJG6o

# Environment
STATIC_DIR=../../client

Comment: The PaymentsController.cs   I've used the standard code taken from STRIPE's documention in GITHUB. The code is too long to display here. When testing the Web App  VS 2019 and IIS Express the Payments Page calls the PaymentsController, gets the correct parameter and calls STRIPE API which displays the Credit Card Payment Page. However when the App is Published the the server and the Domain (in .env) is set to the site's URL the PaymentsController fails to pass control to STRIPE's API and won't go past the Prices.cshtml page

Comment: Can you edit all of this into the question please? This is... really difficult to read and organize mentally.